# What's the efficient way to retrieve "likes" of a post in sql?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, database-performance

So I have two tables, 'videos' and 'video_likes'. The 'videos' table looks like this:

```
id | creator | url        | likes
1  |  5      |https://... |  10
2  |  8      |https://... |  20
3  |  4      |https://... |  30
4  |  2      |https://... |  40
```

And 'video_likes' table looks like this:

```
id | video_id | like_user_id
1  |  2       |   8
2  |  2       |   5
3  |  4       |   2
```

As you can see both are basic tables. Ok Now here is the fun part. When a user likes/dislikes a post, instead of incrementing and decrementing likes' from 'videos' table, I just update them to be as same as the count of rows in the 'video_likes' table, like this:

```
UPDATE videos SET likes = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM video_likes WHERE video_id = '$video_id') WHERE id = '$video_id'
```

When it is time to fetch the no. of likes of the video, I just do this:

```
SELECT likes FROM videos WHERE id = '$video_id' LIMIT 1
```

The problem is that the update query is called each time a user likes or dislikes a video, which could be very expensive I guess. I have three questions related to this problem:

**1**) is there a performance issue when the 'video_likes' table grows to a large number, say a million or a billion?

**2**) Does sql lock the table while updating the count? If yes, will a new insert (a user liking the post while the update is going on) fail? If so, how to prevent this?

**3**) What is the most fastest and efficient way to achieve the same result? I don't want to increment or decrement the likes field, because this will be just a denormalization and there could be inconsistencies in the actual likes count. What would be the right way to do this?

These are a few questions that has been troubling me for the past few days. Hope you'll answer. Regards.

Comment: your major problem is **sql injection*

Comment: I do take some measures to prevent them. Just didn't include that as it isn't part of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend

- Don't recompute; that will just get slower and slower.
- Increment the counter at the same time you `INSERT` into the Likes table.
- When you get so busy that there are hundreds of writes (Inserts, Updates) per *second*, split out the like counter into a parallel table ("vertical partitioning").  This will help avoid conflicts due to the row lock (not table lock) when doing increment a single video like-count, versus other accesses to that table.
- `SELECT likes FROM videos WHERE id = '$video_id' LIMIT 1` does not make sense -- is there more than one row for a video in the `videos` table?  Why?  If so, which one (`limit 1`) do you want?
- Did you also want a "dislike" counter?  Or will you simply 'decrement'.  Think about it.
- `video_likes` does not need an `id`.  Instead, `PRIMARY KEY(video_id, user_id)`.  This will let you prevent a user from repeatedly bumping the count.  (However, this needs checking before doing the increment.)
- etc.

**Dislike**

If "Dislike" is not a feature, but "Un-Like" is, I suggest "Un-Like" be implemented something like

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM video_likes WHERE ...;
UPDATE videos SET like_ct = like_ct - 1 WHERE ...;
COMMIT;
```

That way, the two "like" mechanism would stay perfectly in sync.  This is, to some extent, a mirror image of the "Like" code.

**LIMIT 1**

Think of `LIMIT` only for controlling how much output you get.

- When there is only one row anyway, `LIMIT 1` doesn't change how long the query takes.
- When the query has to sort (`ORDER BY`) to decide which is the first/last/whatever, then it has already done a lot of work; the `LIMIT` merely cuts back on the number of rows delivered.
- On the other hand, when an `INDEX` can be used for the `ORDER BY`, the sort might vanish.  Hence the `LIMIT` controls the number of rows delivered.

**AUTO_INCREMENT or not**

- A table must have a `PRIMARY KEY`.
- If you don't explicitly specify a PK, one is generated for you.  (Not advised.)
- A "natural" PK is on that occurs naturally.  Example, a table of countries could (should) use the standard 2-letter "country codes" -- US, FR, IN, RU, CN, CH, IT, etc.
- `id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` is useful for tables that don't have a "natural" PK.  Or the natural PK is a long string.

In that example with a 4 byte id and a 2-byte country-code, you need two indexes:

```
PRIMARY KEY(id), INDEX(country_code)
```

versus one:

```
PRIMARY KEY(country_code)
```

And the table with `id` is bigger.  (Though not enough bigger in *this* example to really matter.)

In the case of a "many:many", such as your `video_likes`, the `id` hurts performance.  I discuss that [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Comment: Thank You for the detailed explanation. The reason I used 'LIMIT 1' is that because of the thought that sql select would be much faster if we were to limit the number of rows (Please correct me if I am wrong, I am not an expert in sql whatsover :D). Also "Vertical partitioning" is something new.. will do a research on that. No, there is no dislike counter. What I meant by 'dislike' is just the action of undoing the 'like', so decrementing would be a better option. But will incrementing/decrementing cause inconsistency in both the table? Anyway thanks once again for the detailed explanation!

Comment: One more question I have is that, isn't adding an auto increment primary key to every table a good practice?

Comment: @WebDiva — no, not necessarily. A composite primary key makes perfect sense here, a separate ID column would just be redundant.